# I can downplay. Can I upplay?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, word-usage

I can downplay something.

Can I thus "upplay" a thing or not? What do you think?

Comment: You can't "upplay", but you can "upsell" something. Upsell and downplay seem to get used a lot like opposites.

Comment: I read it as "Uplay" and I thought "No, man, you really shouldn't". Damn my eyes

Comment: @Raestloz what does it mean, uplay?

Answer (score 31):

No, unfortunately 'upplay' is not a word. If you want to say the opposite of 'downplay' you can always use words like: magnify, overstate, exaggerate, amplify.

However you can say "[play up](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/play+up)" to mean: to emphasize something.

Comment: Just like you `lower the ante`, and not `down the ante`, vs `up the ante`

Comment: Can't you `raise the ante`?

Comment: I'd say "play up" is the direct antonym of "downplay." For some reason, the word order just gets reversed.

Comment: Notably, you can't "play down" something - it's always "downplay".  [At least in modern English](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=play&allowed_in_frame=0).

Comment: @Bobson You can "play down" something in Modern English.  People play down the importance of issues all the time. E.g., [Google Scholar results](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22play+down+the%22).  You can try news results, too, but that gets into "headline-ese", which isn't always natural modern English.

Comment: Careful with those synonyms - some of those play up ( :) ) the fact that the attention given is undue (overstate, exaggerate), while the others don't.

Comment: @Bobson Check the [n-gram for *play down* vs. *downplay*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=play+down%2Cdownplay&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplay%20down%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdownplay%3B%2Cc0). *downplay* only became more popular than *play down* in the mid-1980's.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - Interesting.  It sounds "wrong" to me, but clearly it does get used. I think Caleb's n-gram explains it best, though - I'm showing my age.

Comment: @Caleb And for UK English, not until 2000, which suggests an American origin for "downplay".

Comment: I think this answer would be dramatically improved by differentiating between words that are the direct opposite of downplay - like emphasize and amplify - and words that bring something extra - criticism.    You use these words in a different context than downplay and its opposite - emphasize.   An English learner could get into trouble if they don't understand this subtlety.

Comment: I wouldn't have recognised "play up" to make something more important. As @MaciejStachowski has hinted, "play up" means to misbehave in some regions, and has negative connotations - strange that TFD doesn't show this?

Answer (score 3):

You wouldn't "up-play", but you could [**overplay**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/overplay) something.

Comment: Overplay is in no way the opposite of down play, though. If you said over play when you meant emphasize, you might embarrass yourself: one is a criticism, the other is not.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Obviously, but so is "downplay" in a way - it points out that something was made less important than it really is. A better opposite for "emphasise" would be "disregard", I think - those two don't imply the wrong judgement.

Answer (score 1):

[talk up](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/talk-someone/thing-up-or-down?q=talk%20up) provides an antonym to *downplay* - it matches the informal/colloquial usage.

*He talked up his work experience to secure the position.*

Comment: This is a good answer! But it would be nice to provide some dictionary citations so the asker can read more, or to give some usage examples. What makes you suggest this phrase in particular?

Comment: Thanks, done! I'm an English speaker of the en_NZ variant - this may be relevant since it feels fairly colloquial.